# Custom intent not received

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've two activities, A and B. Activity A catches the intent with a broadcast receiver, activity B fires it.

Code of activity A :

```
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();         

            if(action.equals(floatyNetworkList.CONNECT_INTENT)){
                Log.v("com.vittorio", "intent catched");
                BluetoothDevice target = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getExtras().get("Device");
                Thread T = new Thread(new ConnectThread(target, mHandler, recmsgs, DDB, "Connecting"));
                T.start();
            }
..
..
```

In activity A I also register the receiver with the following code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
filter.addAction(floatyNetworkList.CONNECT_INTENT);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Code of activity B, my intent is fired when i select an item from my listview:

```
listBtview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterBt, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String,String> selectedFromList =(HashMap<String,String>) (listBtview.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selectedFromList.get("Name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Floaty.class);
        intent.setAction(CONNECT_INTENT);
        intent.putExtra("Device",fetchDevice(selectedFromList.get("Address")));
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
      }                  
});
```

}

Problem is that activity A never receives the intent. I've also added the filter for my custom intent and updated properly my manifest.

Manifest code :

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="com.vittorio.intent.action.CONNECT_INTENT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: do you register your receiver?

Comment: can you show us the code where the BroadcastReceiver is registered or the manifest where it is declared

Comment: Can you post your manifest as well please ?

Comment: I've added both manifest and code where I register the receiver

Comment: why are you using getApplicationContext(), and getBaseContext()?

Comment: I need getBaseContext() for the toast, it's not related to the intent. and i need to call the context of the application with getApplicationContext() because from where i fire the intent i cannot see the app context directly

Comment: yes, you can see it, it's activity context

Comment: Even if a define a var that holds the context of the application things don't change..

Comment: don't use application/base context, use activity context instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(CONNECT_INTENT);
```

or

```
intent = new Intent(CONNECT_INTENT);
```

and, yes, don't use application context, see many posts about it on this site

Comment: Ok now it works, but I just changed the intent to `Intent intent = new Intent();` without modifing the context :).

Comment: ok, I agree it works, but read rhis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this, now I changed the code according to your reply :)